# How can I restrict an included schema

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces

everyone

I have an xsd schema (cft.xsd), which describes a very general top-level structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cft="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="dirType">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="dir" type="cft:dirType"/>
            <xsd:element name="txt">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:attribute name="Name" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\.txt"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="xml">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:any/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="Name" use="required">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\.xml"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="root" type="cft:dirType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

And a second schema (dictionary.xsd), which would describe the content that needs to be in the <cft:xml> node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:l="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" xmlns:cft="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:attribute name="Version" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

So that the document would be something like this:

```
<cft:root xmlns:cft="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft cft.xsd">
    <cft:xml Name="dictionary.xml">
        <root xmlns="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" Version="17.0"/>
    </cft:xml>
</cft:root>
```

My questions are:
1. How can I specify in the dictionary.xsd, that the <root> element defined there can only be nested only in the <cft:xml> element 
    - That is the child of <cft:root> element
    - That has its Name attribute "dictionary.xml"
2. How can I restrict <cft:xml> element from cft.xsd to have the only element named <root> from a **different** namespace than cft?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything, your **dictionary.xsd** should look as below (fix: `complexType` instead of `simpleType` as the type for the `root` element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:l="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" xmlns:cft="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="Version" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

- 1: You cannot; there is no way to control how a global element in one XSD file is going to be used in another XSD file.
- 2: You cannot; there is no way to control the name of the elements that could be accepted as matches for your wildcard. It is possible only to constrain your `xsd:any` with the namespace="##other" attribute - but that is as far you can go.

The only XSD 1.0 alternative that might get you what you want would be to rejig your `cft.xsd` as following:

- make the type of your `xml` global
- use **xsd:redefine** in another XSD file (redefining cft.xsd) and use that one instead, wherever you need to enforce this rule.

NOTE: **xsd:redefine** is not supported by XSD to code binding tools, so you have to consider your XSD use.

Below is an example of a modified **cft.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cft="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" xmlns="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="dirType">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="dir" type="cft:dirType"/>
            <xsd:element name="txt">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:simpleContent>
                        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:attribute name="Name" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\.txt"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:extension>
                    </xsd:simpleContent>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="xml" type="atype"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="atype">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" use="required">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:pattern value="[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\.xml"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="root" type="cft:dirType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

You can then use **custom-cft.xsd** to validate your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSR Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" xmlns:dict="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/cft" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:redefine schemaLocation="cft.xsd">
        <xsd:complexType name="atype">
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:restriction base="atype">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element ref="dict:root"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:redefine>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="dictionary.xsd" namespace="http://www.foo.com/xsd/dictionary"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

As one last recommendation, I would advise against using names such as `xml` since according to the [XML 1.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn): *Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.* I have seen products that simply reject XML documents that use `xml` as tag names, so it is better, for interoperability reasons, to avoid it.